# NSDateformatter returns wrong date from an asp.NET date

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, nsdate, restkit, nsdateformatter

I am using restkit to map my `JSON` into `coredate`. In this `JSON` I find `ASP.Net dates`. When I try to map them in `core date` I sometimes see that the date is one day earlier.

```
Date: "/Date(1389740400000+0100)/"
```

This is how I add a defaultDateFormatter in my code.

```
   RKDotNetDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [RKDotNetDateFormatter new];
        [dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
        dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

        [RKEntityMapping addDefaultDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
```

Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: How are you checking the date? Logging usually applies your local timezone so that could lead to perceived differences...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're running into GMT discrepancies. Try using the `systemTimeZone` instead:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

Comment: Still have the same problem. Some dates are oké but some are not ok.

Comment: When I do stringFromDate, I get this 2014-01-14 23:00:00 +0000 --> normaly this should be 2014-01-15

Comment: Wouldn't that be expected, given the `+0100` at the end of your example date? +0100 from 2014-01-15 is 2014-01-14 23:00:00.

Comment: mm strange how can I disable that then? Because I need it to be 2014-01-15

Comment: You could use string manipulation to strip anything in your JSON to the right of the `+` (including the `+`), but this may not be entirely accurate in all situations. If this date is something you are saving at some other point in the application, you should consider altering that code to save dates in UTC. In your given situation, you feel that 2014-01-15 is correct, but there will be a time/scenario when that is not the correct value.